# How to understand R, and how it works with google's project tango

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file, google-project-tango

I am trying to get a tango project working with android studio and have reached a point of which I can't seem to get past, ad it is in great part to my lack of understanding of things dealing with android in general. Right now I am getting errors, the system cannot seem to find R.id.pose. R.id exists, and has many static members, but pose is not among them. I am getting the code from the samples on github, which I would assume was built to work, so I can only guess that this may be an issue with android studio? I would appreciate knowing more about any of this.

Comment: Do not assume your building environment is the same as the one used to build the original project you found on github. In any case, you really do need to learn about the basics of an Android application. This will help you debug your application so that it eventually builds and runs correctly. You can start with this http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html plus there are some great beginner videos on youtube.com from google i/o on youtube.

Comment: This comment actually helped a ton. I never imagined the android environment would work this way, I come from working in game engines and frameworks where a lot of this direct interfacing with the whole mess of it is optional. Your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/blob/79ed72637568e5619a446124b7d624ae58ebe651/MotionTrackingJava/res/layout/activity_motion_tracking.xml) indicates that R.id.pose is a TextView. I don't want to seem insulting in saying this (I don't know your experience), but in order for the system to find an id (`R.id.something`), it needs to be defined in a layout or resource file (the XML files in the res folder).

Comment: Not at all, this is my first time trying out android. I appreciate the knowledge.